# regular expression in php /##if##(.*?)(.*?)##end_if##/s

Tags: php

I have this string and i need to split it using reqular expression

```
<?php
$matches = null;
$returnValue = preg_match('/##if##(.*?)(.*?)##end_if##/s', '##if##
    First Conditions
    ##if##
    First sub Conditions
    ##end_if##
##end_if##

##if##
    Second Conditions
##end_if##', $matches);
```

the result is

```
array (
  0 => '##if##
    First Conditions
    ##if##
    First sub Conditions
    ##end_if##',
  1 => '',
  2 => '
    First Conditions
    ##if##
    First sub Conditions
    ',
)
```

this is wrong i need return content start with  `##if##`
and end with `##end_if##`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) instead:

```
$returnValue = preg_match_all('/##if##(.*?)(.*?)##end_if##/s', '##if##
    First Conditions
    ##if##
    First sub Conditions
    ##end_if##
##end_if##

##if##
    Second Conditions
##end_if##', $matches);
```

[Eval Here](https://eval.in/707568)

**Prints:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => ##if##
    First Conditions
    ##if##
    First sub Conditions
    ##end_if##
    [1] => ##if##
    Second Conditions
##end_if##
)
```

Comment: ##if##
    First sub Conditions
    ##end_if## I need this also in return array